# Why is QString::number() ignoring most significant digit?

Tags: int, tostring, qstring

This confuses me quite a bit.  What's the deal in the example below?  I'm running this on an armv7 architecture, I've seen some posts online saying that arm doesn't support doubles the same way that an x86 architecture does, but still I'm using an int.

I've seen some c functions in the past that parse numbers from strings and behave with the digit furthest to left being interpreted as the base (e.g. if the leading digit is 0, the function interprets the value as octal or if the leading chars are 0x it interprets it as hex).

If the integer is only a single digit, the string is always empty.  Help?

```
QString bleh;
int i = 9645;
bleh.setNum(i, 10);
// bleh == "645"  Why??
// same thing when bleh = QString::number(i);  Why??
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question here.  It appears that gdb was truncating the first character from these strings.  Not sure why, but it's not the first time I've experienced funny debugger behavior with Qt.